# Determining work / time complexity recursive program

Tags: recursion, big-o, time-complexity

Hi I'm having trouble understanding complexity of recursive programs in my university program with the final in a few days. The language is miranda but I mainly cannot understand how to determine the amount of 'work' on each level of the trace. Can anyone explain how the answer was formulated in this previous test example? Thanks in advance.

```
Example Trace
p9 [1,2,3,4,5,6]

=> 3:[2,3,4,5,6] ++ p9 [2,3,4,5,6]
                           |
                           |
               3:[3,4,5,6] ++ p9 [3,4,5,6]
                                    |
                                    |
                          3:[4,5,6] ++ p9 [4,5,6]
                                              etc.
```

> a) If the length of the input is n,then there are n-1 levels in the computation as one element is removed from the list on each recursive call until the list is of length 1.
>
> b)  The work on the first level is proportional to n + 1
>           because the ++ operator depends on the length of the
>           leftmost list.
>           The work on the next level is proportional to n
>           The work on the next level is proportional to n - 1
>            etc. until the last call when the work is 2 units
>
> c)  Therefore the average work on levels is proportional
>           to n/2.
>
> d)  Therefore the total work is proportional to n^2
>
> e)  Therefore, the complexity is O(n^2)